# Laptop settings resizing web page pushing divs 'off' the page - is there a way around this via code?

Tags: javascript, html

My boss is running a laptop which has a setting which is resizing font sizes and making them larger by about a third.  This is fine but we have a java app running on the site and the div tags are being pushed off of the page because of the increase in font size.  Is there a way to stop font being resized, via code?

Thanks, R.

Comment: Yes that did help.  He had text scaling on and didn't know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the browser, but most use zooming now: see this article: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-two-types-of-browser-zoom.html

I do not think you can stop this, nor should you. What about people who need to larger font size.

Comment: I agree, but it is a very small app and I/we are trying to maintain consistency of use.  I am really looking for a compromise that will suit everybody and to be more aware of the issues.

Comment: I see your thought process, but if you have a user that is using the accessibility features then you should make your app accessible.

Comment: I did manage to come up with a compromise which worked well + or - two step scaling.  Initially I just didn't know why my div would disappear which threw me.  I also changed the div so that it was simply positioned at the bottom of the screen rather than defining a distance from the top.  It works, I like it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the problem is in your DIVs, not in your fonts. Unless your text contains huge strings with no "breaking" characters in them, a DIV should merely set itself to its parent's width as default behavior.